# cometd setup: using dojo and apache

Tags: cometd

Can some body point out how to set up a server and client for cometd application.

i have dojo, and appache server ..

when i browsed through , came across jetty server. Im not sure whether both apache and jetty servers are needed to set the server side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: http://cometd.org/book/export/html/65

the servlet should work on Tomcat as well as Jetty. It's just that the cometd implementation was done by Jetty people. But it's a standard servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example that i have built it for jboss : [Cometd-struts2 example on jboss](https://github.com/harrybabu/struts2-cometd)